# Can't get the "Medical tour" from Dr. Troy

Tags: fallout-2

I have [Doctor](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Doctor) at 80% but I still don't get the option of getting a medical tour from [Dr. Troy](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Troy) in [Vault City](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Vault_8). He doesn't ask me to get an example of [Jet](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Deliver_a_sample_of_jet_to_Dr._Troy) either. I think I struck a conversation with him before my doctor skill was 75%, which I believe is the minimum skill level for the tour. Have I burnt my chance forever now? The only thing Dr. Troy offers me is healing, nothing more.

Answer (score 4):

**You didn't by chance blackmail him, did you?**

I tested several scenarios and blackmail was the only way that I was able to have the dialogue not appear. It also prevents the dialogue to complete the [Jet quest](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Deliver_a_sample_of_jet_to_Dr._Troy) from appearing. You could take the tour first, *then* blackmail him.

Whether or not you are a bit of a jerk to him in the dialogue doesn't seem to matter. Merely suggesting blackmail also does not seem to have an effect.

---

(scenarios 7 and 8 are the only two which cause the medical tour option to go away)

These tests were on a character with 2 Charisma, -10% speech, and 4 intelligence. An intelligence lower than 4 means that he won't talk to you at all. (that should rule out those stats having a positive effect)

### Scenario 1:

1. Speak to Dr. Troy with [75% doctor skill](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Vault_City_Training).
2. Accept quest to collect Jet.
3. Dialogue for the medical tour is available.
4. Tour taken, doctor skill increased to 80%.

### Scenario 2:

1. Speak to Dr. Troy with 75% doctor skill.
2. Decline quest to collect Jet.
3. Dialogue for the medical tour is available.
4. Tour taken, doctor skill increased to 80%.

### Scenario 3:

1. Speak to Dr. Troy with 74% doctor skill.
2. Accept quest to collect Jet, end dialogue.
3. Increase doctor skill to 75%.
4. Dialogue for the medical tour is now available.
5. Tour taken, doctor skill increased to 80%.

### Scenario 4:

1. Speak to Dr. Troy with 74% doctor skill.
2. Decline quest to collect Jet, end dialogue.
3. Increase doctor skill to 75%.
4. Dialogue for the medical tour is now available.
5. Tour taken, doctor skill increased to 80%.

### Scenario 5:

1. Speak to Dr. Troy with 75% doctor skill and -1000 karma.
2. Dialogue for the medical tour is available.
3. Tour taken, doctor skill increased to 80%.

### Scenario 6:

1. Speak to Dr. Troy with 74% doctor skill.
2. Accept quest to collect Jet.
3. Finish quest to collect Jet, end dialogue.
4. Increase doctor skill to 75%.
5. Dialogue for the medical tour is now available.
6. Tour taken, doctor skill increased to 80%.

### Scenario 7:

1. Speak to Dr. Troy with 74% doctor skill.
2. Quest to collect Jet is brought up.
3. Blackmail the doctor for requesting Jet.
4. Increase doctor skill to 75%.
5. **Dialogue for the medical tour is not available.**

### Scenario 8:

1. Speak to Dr. Troy with 75% doctor skill.
2. Accept quest to collect Jet.
3. Dialogue for the medical tour is now available.
4. Blackmail the doctor.
5. **Dialogue for the medical tour is not available.**